# Scanning over WiFi with Dell e525w multifunction printer

Tags: scanner

How to get scanning over WiFi up and running with the Dell e525w multifunction printer.

Not really a question, just posting here since it hasn't been asked yet and it needed a bit of research to find out how to do it.

Assumes you already have the printer connected to your WiFi.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, but since only samba is required it should work pretty much on every system you can create a samba share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No driver is necessary for scanning, as the printer has the ability to mount a samba share and put scanner output there.

Ubuntu side:

1. Create a folder, right-click and go to network share options
2. set "share folder" checkbox
3. set "allow others to edit and remove files"
4. (optionally) set "allow guest access"

You might need to install samba, if your user account has the required privilege the software center will prompt you to install automatically when you create the share.

Find out IP address of your Ubuntu box:

```
$ ifconfig -a
```

Now on to the printer side setup, go to the admin panel using your browser using the IP address of the printer.

Your printer will normally display the IP in the front LCD display.

Default user for the admin panel is "admin", with no password required.

1. Go to "Address Book" -> Server Tab
2. click "create" button on one of the empty entries
3. fill out form, specifically:

   - protocol -> SMB
   - server address -> IP if your Ubuntu box
   - share -> the share name you gave to your folder
   - port -> 139
4. save and apply (in case it fails to properly save the IP on first attempt, edit the entry and enter IP again, it should work properly then)

Scanning:

Now in order to scan, press the "scan" button on your printer, and select "Scan to network", a list will come up next showing the list of known network shares, it should show the one you just configured in the admin panel.

Select the share, and start the scanning process.

When scanning is finished, the resulting file will pop up in your share folder on your Ubuntu box.

Comment: Was unable to replicate on e515dw. The "Address Book" on this device only allows for "Speed Dial" Fax setup. I know it's a different model, but looking all over for solution to Ubuntu 14.04 and your post was the closest i've come.